# Prevent Excel VBA code interruption with Esc key

Tags: vba, excel

How can I prevent Excel VBA Code from being interrupted by the user by pressing the `Esc` Key?

I'm trying the following code on `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Application.DataEntryMode = True

    Call WebPage
End Sub
```

But it's not working since if I press Esc when the workbook opens, the code breaks:

[image]

So it seems the code is interrupted even before the workbook opens.
Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your workbook is big enough that there is a time delay between opening and running code, leaving an opportunity for the user to hit esc in the meantime. Perhaps instead of calling WebPage on the workbook opening, you could have the file be simply a 'landing page' with instructions and a single button to click. This gives the user control over executing the macro, but also gives you time to load your disabling of the escape key before the macro is run.

Also, if you have confidence that your error handling will return all functionality to normal you could use this instead:

```
Application.InterActive = False
```

This would prevent any key instructions being entered, including esc & command break.

Comment: thank you so much, this is an interesting idea! The WebPage procedure in my actual code is meant to validate the user, that's the reason why it is being called at startup. Perhaps I can just show a userform on startup?

Comment: That could do what you want - however first ask yourself why you are attempting to validate the user - is this a security issue? Keep in mind that Excel code is not necessarily secure against a committed individual. You could perhaps consider having the code attempt to pull data from a workbook on a shared network drive, and if the user does not have access to that network folder it would fail. Note that I've never had to secure any data given to users, so take my advice with a grain of salt.